# ERRO EM UM PROGRAMA EM C

Tags: c

Bom, meu meu professor de Estrutura de dados passou uma atividade e na ultima questa pede o seguinte:

> Implemente um programa que leia um vetor de 5 elementos do tipo inteiro e mostre, em outro módulo, todos os números lidos acrescidos de 10 unidades.

Eu conseguir fazer o código, só que quando é pra acrescer 10 unidades surgiu um valor 3 que eu não de onde saiu kkkkkk

```
    #include <stdio.h>


//em outro módulo, todos os números lidos acrescidos de 10 unidades.
acrescido(int vet[], int q){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    //v[i] = i;
    printf("%d\n",vet[i]+10);
    }
}

// leia um vetor de 5 elementos do tipo inteiro e mostre -INÍCIO
main(){
    int v[6];
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    v[i] = i;
    printf("Posição[%d] = %d\n", i-1,i);
    }
    printf("%d\n",acrescido(v,6));
}
// FIM
```

**Oque eu não entendendo é esse 3 aqui na saida**

```
Posição[0] = 1
Posição[1] = 2
Posição[2] = 3
Posição[3] = 4
Posição[4] = 5

10
11
12
13
14
15
3
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

esse 3 aí na SaídA é por causa de Que você colocou para escrever o retorno da função acrescidos ,

```
printf("%d\n",acrescido(v,6)); /// esse %d vai escrever o valor que for retornado da função**texto em negrito**
```

e dependendo de cada momento em Que você executar esse código , ele vai mostrar valores aleatórios , e então se você colocar para retornar algum valor dessa função , aí esse será o que será escrito no Final no lugar desse 3

```
int acrescido(int vet[], int q)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("\nposicao[%d] => %d\n",i, vet[i]);
        printf("%d\n",vet[i]+10);
    }
    return 4096;
}
```

e outra coisa é Que você criou um vetor de **seis** posições e no primeiro loop dentro da **função main** inseriu números a partir da ***segunda*** posição , pois a primeira é a posição zero do vetor , e lá na função **acrescido** , colocou um Loop para escrever os números a partir de zero , e com isso ele escreve o primeiro como Sendo um número desconhecido , ou Lixo de memória , . ,,